# How to make a node point to a taxonomy term page instead of its own?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, ubercart

I have a view that displays a group of "featured" nodes of different categories (taxonomy terms). These featured nodes can be ubercart products or just a generic node with an image and, maybe, some text.

They show up one by one, as a slideshow (Views Slideshow module) inside a block on the front page. This view is based on the new_products view from uc_views module.
Each node shows up as an image linked to to the node and, when a product, a buy button under the image.

I want some of these nodes to go, when clicked, to a taxonomy term page instead of the node "page".

How can i do that? If you need more details, feel free to ask.

Comment: i would like to thank the person who downvoted my question without adding a comment with the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Views, for a field you can configure it to 'Output this field as a link', then set the 'Link path' by using the 'Replacement patterns' tokens provided.

You will need to make sure your view has a field for the 'Taxonomy: Term ID' and its weight is further up the list than your image field.

You'll set your image field's settings to 'Output this field as a link', then set the 'Link path' to e.g.

```
taxonomy/term/[tid]
```

Just be sure to use the proper 'Replacement patterns' tokens provided by your view.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :) Gah, i need to use my brain sometimes. lol